# Is this a fremontodron vine or flannel vine and what is the zucchini looking things growing from it?

Tags: vines

This is a vining plant with leaves similar to a maple and has yellow flowers and something that is long and green hanging from it.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like luffa to me. The "zucchini looking things" are female flowers/fruits. Wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luffa) here.

BTW (assume my id is correct), luffa is delicious and nutricious. When forgotten to be picked up, it matures into scrubbing sponge - one of the best, if not the best sponges you could possibly have.